# Splitting each element of a string array into a new array in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm very new to c#.

I've imported an array called txtImport from a text file. In it contains 1000 poker hands for two players, so actually 2000 poker hands.

Each line in the file is structured as follows:

8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC

Where the first 5 are player one's cards, and the second 5 are player two's.

The array contains 1000 hands. I would like to split this array into two arrays, one containing all of player one's hands, one containing all of player two's. So each element needs to be split down the middle and the space deleted.

I have no idea how to go about doing this I have attempted a lot of things but none are correct. I want to use a foreach loop to go through each element, cut it into two, delete the space in the middle, then assign the first half of the cut string into a new array called playerOneHands, and the second half of the cut string into a new array called playerTwoHands.

But I'm totally lost on the syntax or how this is approached in c#. I think I'm incorrectly approaching it from a python way. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Edit:

Hi everyone, this was eventually solved using the code:

```
string[] txtImport = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\C#\poker.txt"); // Importing each line of the text file into an element in an array called txtImport

            string[] playerOneHands = new string[txtImport.Length];
            string[] playerTwoHands = new string[txtImport.Length];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in txtImport)
            {
                playerOneHands[i] = item.Substring(0, 14); // dividing the import array into two arrays each containing the list of hands of either player
                playerTwoHands[i] = item.Substring(15, 14);
                i++
            }
```

Comment: When you say _"delete the space in the middle"_, do you mean you would take "8C TS KC 9H 4S" and add it to your array as "8CTSKC9H4S"; or do you mean delete the space inbetween the two new strings? 8C TS KC 9H 4S<thisSpaceHere>7D 2S 5D 3S AC

Comment: `I have attempted a lot of things but none are correct` but that is what the site is for - post *code* you are having trouble with and we try to help fix it.  This is just asking for someone to write code for you.  Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Hi plutonix.As I said I'm new to c#. I'm not asking for anyone to code for me, this is what I had written:

foreach (var item in playerOneHands)
            {
                item.Remove(0, 14);
            }

            foreach (var item in playerTwoHands)
            {
                item.Remove(15, 14);
            }

But no luck, it just doesn't remove the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve your problem, albeit it's not very robust:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] txtImport = new string[] { "TS TS TS TS TS 3S 3S 3S 3S 3S",
                                            "KH KH KH KH KH AH AH AH AH AH",
                                            "8C 8C 8C 8C 8C 7D 7D 7D 7D 7D" };
        string[] playerOne = new string[999];
        string[] playerTwo = new string[999];
        int i = 0;


        foreach (var item in txtImport)
        {
            playerOne[i] = item.Substring(0, 14);
            playerTwo[i] = item.Substring(15, 14);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use some math. You always have an even number of hands and an odd number of spaces. I.e., the length of the string is always odd. Using integer arithmetic, you can divide the length of the string by 2. This yields a truncated result, i.e. the length of one player's hands without the space in the middle. The starting index of the second player's hands is this length + 1 to skip the space in the middle.

```
string[] txtImport = File.ReadAllLines(myFile);

string[] playerOneHands = new string[txtImport.Length];
string[] playerTwoHands = new string[txtImport.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < txtImport.Length; i++) {
    string hands = txtImport[i]; // "8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC"
    int halfLength = hands.Length / 2;
    playerOneHands[i] = hands.Substring(0, halfLength);
    playerTwoHands[i] = hands.Substring(halfLength + 1); // The remaining part up to the end.
}
```

If you know that all the lines have the same length, you can calculate `halfLength` before starting the loop.

```
int halfLength = txtImport[0].Length / 2;
for (...
```

Comment: I like your answer because it's more complete/robust and considerate of the length of the initial array.

Comment: and works with any number of hands per player.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes For a second, I thought you meant any number of hands alltogether :) That would have been a tall order, especially with File.ReadAllLines(myFile);. But yes, the algorithm itself is elegant and can be easily modified to work with any reasonable "any number of hands" in all interpretations. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem I understand that each card is separated by a space therefore I would use the `Split` method and specify the space character as the separator like so:

```
var line = "8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC";
var allCards = line.Split(' ');
```

Secondly, I understand that you want to assign the first five cards to player one and the next five to player two. I would use `Linq` to achieve this like so:

```
var playerOneHands = allCards.Take(5);
var playerTwoHands = allCards.Skip(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use link to perform this on the whole array you got:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] hands = new[] {
        "8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "2C TS KC 9H 4S 8D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "3C TS KC 9H 4S 9D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "4C TS KC 9H 4S 6D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "5C TS KC 9H 4S 5D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "6C TS KC 9H 4S 4D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "9C TS KC 9H 4S 3D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        "7C TS KC 9H 4S 2D 2S 5D 3S AC",
        };

        var split = hands
            .Select(s => // select is used to split it in first 5 + second 5 using 
                new      // IEnumeratble<T>.Take(5) and .Skip(5) after splitting
                {        // string.Join glues the splits on " " back together
                    p1 = string.Join(" ", s.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Take(5)).Trim(),

                    p2 = string.Join(" ", s.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(5)).Trim()
                })
        .ToList();

        // I provided the stringsplit-options to get rid of "empty" splits on "   ".

        var p1 = split.Select(s => s.p1).ToArray();
        var p2 = split.Select(s => s.p2).ToArray();

        foreach (var t in p1)
            Console.WriteLine("P1:   " + t);

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var t in p2)
            Console.WriteLine("P2:   " + t);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
P1:   8C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   2C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   3C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   4C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   5C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   6C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   9C TS KC 9H 4S
P1:   7C TS KC 9H 4S

P2:   7D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   8D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   9D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   6D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   5D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   4D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   3D 2S 5D 3S AC
P2:   2D 2S 5D 3S AC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.Split` method to split the lines in the file:

```
string[] lines = fileText.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

To get the first half of the string, you can use the `String.Substring` method.

```
List<string> playerOneHands = new List<string>();
List<string> playerTwoHands = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    playerOneHands.Add(line.Substring(0, 14));
    playerTwoHands.Add(line.Substring(15, 14));
}
```